# How can you dynamically add a new tab to a tab-panel in Red

Tags: red

Let's say you have a tab-panel like so :

```
editor: layout [
    below
    t: tab-panel 350x350 [
        "tab 1" [
            below
            b: button 75x25 "Interpret" on-click [do a/text ]
            a: area 320x250
        ]
    ]
]

view editor
```

How could I dynamically add a new tab to it so that has the contents of the current tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are several ways to add a new tab dynamically, but in all cases, it boils down to adding:

- A tab label as a `string!` to `t/data` block.
- A corresponding `panel` face `object!` to `t/pane` block.

Here is a fully working example code:

```
tab1: [
    below
    button 75x25 "Interpret" on-click [do face/parent/pane/2/text ]
    area 320x250
]

editor: layout compose/deep/only [
    below
    button "add tab" [
        append t/data "tab 2"
        append t/pane make face! [type: 'panel pane: layout/only tab1]
    ]
    t: tab-panel 350x350 ["tab 1" (tab1)]
]
view editor
```

Some remarks:

- `tab1` definition has been externalized, so its definition can be reused for another tab content (as per your request).
- `a:` word has been removed as it cannot be duplicated, access to the current `area` face in current tab panel is now done by walking up the face tree. `b:` definition has been dropped for same reason (and it's not used anyway).

Examples of dynamic behaviors and dynamic face construction (without VID dialect) are available [here](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/tests/view-test.red). `tab-panel` face type is described [there](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_tab_panel).

Comment: Can you explain what compose/deep/only is used for in this context?

Comment: Oh nevermind I see, you use that with the ["tab 1" (tab1) ]