# Making GUI objects in Red language

Tags: user-interface, object, rebol, red

I have following simple code for a small panel:

```
view [
    t: text "label"
    f: field
    button "Click here" [t/text: f/text]    ]
```

But I have to make 2 of them and put them on one window. I want to create single object class and make 2 objects out of it. I see that objects can be created as follows:

```
obj: object [
    view [
        t: text "label"
        f: field
        button "Click here" [t/text: f/text] ]  ]

view [
    obj
    obj     ]
```

But I get following error:

```
*** Script Error: VID - invalid syntax at: [obj obj]
*** Where: do
*** Stack: view layout cause-error
```

How can this be done? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I tried with `do` but could manage only with `does`:

```
  myview: object [
      show: does [view[
        below
        t: text "1st time"
        f: field "Enter value"
        button "Click here" [f/text "clicked"]
        area] ] ]

  myview/show

  print "READY TO SHOW 2nd OBJECT: "
  myview2: copy myview
  myview2/show
```

Comment: You are still mixing dialects which is why it won&amp;#39;t work. View only understands the vid dialect. You can preprocess the block in the do dialect and feed the block of vid dialect to view

Comment: It seems they are 2 different languages, connected very thinly.

Comment: They are two different dialects of the same language.

Comment: I tried in this as well as previous question, but I am not able to produce an example with `do` (I could make `collect` and `keep` work). Can you provide an answer using `do` for this purpose? (Also see edit in my question above).

Comment: http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-guide.html#section-70

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809351/how-can-you-dynamically-add-a-new-tab-to-a-tab-panel-in-red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create single object class and make 2 objects out of it.

There is no object *class* system in Red, so you should really try first to grasp the basic Red concepts before trying more complex GUI constructs. Red is a very flexible data-oriented language, so you can use that to your advantage by, for example, building parametrized block templates, and assembling them to form a correct block of VID code. Here is an example:

```
make-row: func [label [string!] but-label [string!]][
    compose [
        t: text (label)
        f: field
        b: button (but-label) [face/extra/1/text: face/extra/2/text]
        do [b/extra: reduce [t f]]
    ]
]

view compose [
    (make-row "label" "Click") return
    (make-row "label2" "Click2")
]
```

Understanding the face tree (analog to the HTML DOM, just way simpler), is an important part of mastering Red's GUI system. As there is no much documentation yet (you can start with http://docs.red-lang.org), you are welcome to ask live questions on [red/help](https://gitter.im/red/help) Gitter room.

Comment: What is ` do [b/extra: reduce [t f]]` doing?  Why not `face/pane` rather than `face/extra`?

Comment: The `/pane` facet is used for constructing the face tree that defines which widget contains others. You don't want `button` to have child widgets, so there is no purpose in using `/pane` there. The `/extra` field is a free facet that can be used to attach any data to the face object. In this case, we want to save a reference to the text and field faces, so that we can use it when the button is clicked. Please re-read the [documentation](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_face_object).

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for are styles and not objects in order to create a layout. Until now there is no official stylize function in Red. But you can create your layout dynamically like this

```
view repeat i 2 [
    tname: to-word rejoin ['t i]
    fname: to-word rejoin ['f i]
    append v: [] compose/deep [ 
        (to-set-word tname) text "label"
        (to-set-word fname) field
        button "click here"   [
          (to-set-path  compose [(tname) text])  
          (to-path  compose [(fname) text])
        ] 
    ] 
]
```

You can just append a predefined block of words many times to the block you want to view and you will get repeated elements.

```
 txt_btn: [
    t: text "label"
    f: field
    button "Click here" [t/text: f/text] 
 ] 
 view append append [] txt_btn txt_btn
```

The problem arises as you refer to a named element in your block. But a word can not point to more than one element of the repeated elements, therefore the usage of compose in the complete solution in order to create unique names.

Maybe there is a bug in Red because I thought `compose/deep` would also do parentheses deep inside and not need more compose –

Comment: Yes, it is working! Some explanation of code will also be very helpful.

Comment: How can I access each of these panels/objects (what is their name or symbol) if the program wants to interact with them separately?

Comment: This is probably a better way to build up layouts. You can modify the objects afterwards this way.

Comment: But it is clearly not remaining simple anymore which was the theme of Red language.

Answer (score 2):

To work with *objects* instead of in the *VID* dialect, replace `view` with `layout`:

```
lay: layout [
    t: text "label"
    f: field
    button "Click here" [t/text: f/text]
]

view lay
```

You can then inspect it like any other object: `?? lay`.

For example, to access the contents of `lay` with `pane`:

```
>> ? lay/pane/1
```

However, a more useful function may be `dump-face`:

```
>> dump-face lay
 Type: window Style: none Offset: 833x548 Size: 270x45 Text: "Red: untitled"
     Type: text Style: text Offset: 10x10 Size: 80x24 Text: "label"
     Type: field Style: field Offset: 100x10 Size: 80x24 Text: none
     Type: button Style: button Offset: 190x9 Size: 70x25 Text: "Click here"
== make object! [
    type: 'window
    offset: 833x548
 ...
```

`panel`s are useful to group objects together:

```
>> dump-face blay: layout [p: panel button "hi"]
 Type: window Style: none Offset: none Size: 292x220 Text: none
     Type: panel Style: panel Offset: 10x10 Size: 200x200 Text: none
     Type: button Style: button Offset: 220x9 Size: 62x25 Text: "hi"
== make object! [
    type: 'window
    offset: none
    ...
```

But it's probably easier to use the *VID* dialect with `compose` to build up stuff first.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809351/how-can-you-dynamically-add-a-new-tab-to-a-tab-panel-in-red/)

Comment: `view lay` works but I want another object `lay2 copy lay` which also works but then I want to show them in one view and `view [lay lay2]` throws error: ` VID - invalid syntax at: [lay lay2]`. How can I show both lay and lay2 in one view?