# GUI elements from a function not being displayed in Red language

Tags: function, user-interface, rebol, red

I am using following code to try to get GUI elements from a function:

```
  mypanelfn: func[] [
    collect[
      repeat i 10 [ 
        print append copy "i in loop: " i
        keep [t: text]  keep append copy "message: " i
        keep [field "entry"    
              button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return]]]]

  view [ 
    do [mypanelfn]]
```

There are no error messages and loop go on all right and a windows is also displayed. But this is only a small empty windows without any text, fields or buttons.

What is wrong with this code?

Edit: putting `probe` before `collect` shows (I have added line breaks for clarity):

```
[t: text "message: 1" field "entry" button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return 
t: text "message: 2" field "entry" button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return 
t: text "message: 3" field "entry" button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return 
t: text "message: 4" field "entry" button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return 
t: text "message: 5" field "entry" button "Click" [t/text: "clicked"] return
```

Comment: Actually, `view mypanelfn` works perfectly. All GUI elements are being displayed. But clicking any button changes only last text label, and not corresponding text label. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Use `self/text`

Comment: Which `text` entry? I am not able to add `self` anywhere with success.

Comment: Btw, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46253902/5798459 solves this problem

Comment: https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/tests/view-test.red has better examples of dynamically constructing view objects

Comment: https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html#_do for `self`, but it's possibly better to ask that in another question :)

Comment: Also, do check with our communities here rebol: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol
red: https://gitter.im/red/red/welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once again; you need unique names for elements you want to address. Here a solution with reduce instead of compose

```
mypanelfn: func[] [
  collect[
    repeat i 10 [ 
      tname: to-word rejoin ['t i]
      print append copy "i in loop: " i
      keep  reduce [to-set-word tname 'text]  keep append copy "message: " i
      keep reduce [
       'field "entry" 'button "Click"  reduce  [ 
          to-set-path  reduce [
             tname 'text ]
            "clicked" ]
      'return ] ] ] ]
```

I recommend that you use the commands in the console to see what they do. E.g.

`rejoin ['t i]` creates a string `"t1"`with t and the (reduced/get-)value of i.

`to-word` changes that to a Red(bol) word `t1`

`to-setword tname`   creates a set-word `t1:`

`to-set-path reduce [tname 'text ]`creates a set-path  `t1/text:`

Comment: Yes, it works very well. The text elements get labelled as `t1, t2` etc and clicking buttons affect corresponding text element only. It will be useful if you can explain how this labeling is working, i.e. use of `to-word, rejoin, to-set-word, to-set-path` etc.

Comment: What is `to-set-path` for?

Answer (score 3):

This method does not require setting any variables—it works by containing each iteration of faces within a common parent (`panel`):

```
view collect [
    keep [below space 0x0]
    repeat i 10 [
        keep compose/deep [
            panel [
                origin 0x0
                text (rejoin ["Message Number: " i])
                field "entry"
                button "Click" [face/parent/pane/1/text: "clicked"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

`face/parent` is the `panel` face whose first child (`pane/1`) is the text box (`origin` does not create a face).

Comment: @rnso My code segments adhere to the Rebol/Red coding style guide—please refer to that before modifying.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need the function there, however:

```
view mypanelfn
```

Works.

Note: the equivalent code in Rebol requires `layout`: `view layout mypanelfn`

The reason this happens is because `view` processes `blocks!` (anything inside `[]`). So you don't have to `do` it.

In general, it's better to think of Red as a functional, message passing language. Everything is an expression, in contrast to imperative languages with procedures and statements.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me in rebol/view:

```
lay: mypanelfn
insert head lay 'across
view layout lay
```

[image]

I think while you're learning this stuff you need to look at the generated VID code to check that there are no problems before trying to View it.

Comment: Output being returned from function seems all right (see edit in my question above). Then why my code is not working in Red?

Comment: Your code does not work for me in Red. The error is: `*** Script Error: lay has no value; *** Where: head; *** Stack: mypanelfn ` (I have added semicolons instead of line breaks).